# ag-grid angualr i want duplicate the selected row data inside same grid i.e i want copy and pate selected row on button click in the same grid

Tags: angular8, ag-grid-angular

In Ag-grid angular,i have button clone row, i will select a row inside grid and click on clone row it should create same row once again in specified index,i was able to achieve this using following code

## in app.ts::

clone Row(){

var selectedRowsIndex = this.gridOptions.api.getSelectedNodes();

```
     var index = selectedRowsIndex[0].rowIndex
var selectedRows = this.gridOptions.api.getSelectedRows();
const temp =  [...selectedRows] 
for (var i = 0; i < selectedRows.length; i++) {
  temp[i].B_CLONE = true;
  temp[i].SNO = 3;

}
this.gridOptions.api.insertItemsAtIndex(++index,temp)
```

}

```
<button class="btn btn-info ml-3" (click)="cloneRow()">Clone Row</button>
```

```html
<button class="btn btn-info ml-3" (click)="cloneRow()">Clone Row</button>
```

Issue i am facing was, after cloning a row(insertItemsAtIndex)

1. existing row also being changed with new clone row if add any value i.e s.no in gird
2. if i edit any of 2 rows duplicated and change any value in any one cell of row getting changed n both the rows are changed.

i want to two rows independent of their values

i am attaching screen short for easy understanding.

[original grid before clone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LET92.png)

[grid after clone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBR7C.png)

[grid after clone changing cell value in one row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYnUV.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to deep clone and assign the the `temp` object like this:

```
this.gridOptions.api.insertItemsAtIndex(++index,Object.assign({}, temp));
```

Instead `Object.assign({}, temp)` you can also clone the object like this (the old school way of cloning):

```
this.gridOptions.api.insertItemsAtIndex(++index,JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(temp)));
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, 1.could you please explain what is mistake i was doing,why i need to deep clone and update row.                      2.why  my original row update also being changed with new data after update.

Comment: @Ashok the line: const temp =  [...selectedRows]  here you are just copying reference, hence any change in temp will reflect in selectedRows and vice versa. Read about Deep vs Shallow copy, And this is not just Javascript limited concept.